# Web3py merkle tree support

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py, merkle-tree

I am trying to implement a merkle tree just like merkletreejs but python does not have any good libraries that support keccak256 and sorted keccak256 trees. Does anyone know of a good python lib for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and there is one. Just check from https://github.com/tokenchain/moodyeth
Check for the usage on merkle proofs.
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tokenchain/moodyeth/main/docs/moody/m/kyc/merkletree.html detail source code.

Comment: I ran this and it is giving me different values than the merkletreejs version. 

I am running this example
with the input list as 
["0xethaddress1","0xethaddress2","0xethaddress3"] etc instead of "abc" and it is not matching 
https://github.com/tokenchain/moodyeth/blob/main/moody/m/kyc/merkletree.py#L133